# Alternative implementation of Ackermann function in C

Tags: c, assembly, recursion, mips

I wrote a program in C which calculates the **Ackermann** values for 2 non-negative integers entered by the user. The program checks if the integers are non-negative and if they are it calculates the Ackermann value of them and then asks for new input or exit. The program works fine in C and I have no problem with it. Here is my code:

```
int ackermann(int m, int n){
        if (m == 0) return n + 1;
        if (n == 0) return ackermann(m - 1, 1);
        return ackermann(m - 1, ackermann(m, n - 1));
}
```

BUT, in fact, for the needs of a university lesson we use a modified version of C(basically the same but with some different syntax rules) which simulates the syntax and the rules of MIPS Assembly language. More specifically, we use registers to manipulate all the data except from arrays and structs. Also, we cannot use for, while, or do-while loops and we use **if** and **goto** statements instead. So I wrote the following program in this language(as I said it is no more than C with different syntax). My problem is that it works only for (x,0) and (0,y) user inputs(x and y are non-negative numbers). It doesn't work for (4,1), (3,2) and generally all inputs that have no zero. I understand that it cannot work efficiently for very large numbers like (10,10) due to the vast stack of these calculations. But I want it to work for some simple inputs like Ackermann(3,1) == 13. For more on Ackermann function please see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function
Here is my code:

```
//Registers --- The basic difference from C is that we use registers to manipulate data
int R0=0,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9,R10,R11,R12,R13,R14,R15,R16,R17,R18,R19,R20,R21,
R22,R23,R24,R25,R26,R27,R28,R29,R30,R31;

int ackermann(int m, int n){

    R4 = m;
    R5 = n;

    if(R4 != 0)
        goto outer_else;
    R6 = R5 + 1;
    return R6;

    outer_else:
        if(R5 != 0)
            goto inner_else;
        R7 = R4 - 1;
        R6 = ackermann(R7, 1);
        return R6;

        inner_else:
            R8 = R5 - 1;
            R9 = ackermann(R4, R8);
            R10 = R4 - 1;
            R6 = ackermann(R10, R9);
            return R6;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem is that those register values are defined as global variables and they're being updated by an inner call to `ackermann()`, while an outer call depends on those values not changing. For example, take a look at the `inner_else` clause in your register version of `ackermann()`: it calls `ackermann(R4, R8)`, and in the next statement depends on the current value of R4 but the recursive call alters the setting of R4 before it reaches the assignment statement.

Two common solutions:

1. Define your registers as local variables and let the compiler keep track of per function call state for you.
2. On entry to your `ackermann()` function, manually save the state of all registers and then restore same on exit.

Although solution 1 is easier, I suspect your teacher might prefer solution 2, because it illustrates the kind of technique used by a compiler to deal with actual register management in its generated assembly code.

Comment: Regarding the second solution, which registers should I push and pop? Where in the function should I restore them(pop)? Thanks for your answer:)

Comment: The safe, naive solution would be to save (restore) all registers at entry (all exit points). A more efficient approach would be to save only the registers that are modified anywhere in the recursive function and then restore those same registers on exit. Most efficient would be to save on demand before writing, which saves only those registers that actually change. The disadvantage of the latter option is you have to keep track of which registers you modified (so you know which ones to restore), which requires another data structure and some additional logic.

Comment: I prefer to go the safe way.. I changed the code according to what you told me but still doesn't work. First I used 6 global variables **int a,b,c,d,e,f;** and then in the Ackermann function after the assignments **R4 = m; R5 = n;** I added:                         /*PUSH*/
a = R4;
b = R5;
c = R7;
d = R8;
e = R9;
f = R10;                                                               and BEFORE EACH return I added:                                     /*POP*/
a = R4;
b = R5;
c = R7;
d = R8;
e = R9;
f = R10;           What am I doing wrong? Please help:) Thank you @Marc Cohen

Comment: Two problems: 1) If you are storing your register state in global variables, those variables will suffer from the same fate as the original register definitions. You need to store that state on the stack. Try defining a-f as local variables. 2) The POP function you've described is the same as your PUSH function -- it should be the inverse, i.e. instead of a = R4, you want to pop by doing R4 = a.

Comment: Thank you very much! It finally works:) Sorry, for the POP, I just forgot to inverse the assignments..